Powerpoint VBA basics: textbox on change event
I have a slide presentation in Office 2010 and would like to use a textbox as input for a calculation and display the result in another textbox when the value changes.
With some help from StackOverflow I found the text box reference: Slides(2).Shapes(12) - so this code should do something? -
Sub Slide2_Shape12_Change()
    MsgBox "Hello!"
End Sub

..but nothing happens when I enter a new value in the box. Stuck already! Please excuse the simple question.

The code needs to be in the code-behind Module for the right Slide and the name of the Sub needs to be exactly right. The simplest way of doing this, once you have added the TextBox into the Slide, with the Developer tab showing in the PowerPoint ribbon, select the TextBox then click on the 'View Code' button. It should take you to the right Module and populate it with the 'signature' of the Sub which should be (if, for example, your TextBox is called TextBox1)
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Within this Sub, you can then do what you want eg send the text to the Immediate window
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim text As String
    text = TextBox1.text
    Debug.Print "'" & text & "'"
End Sub

... or, if your other TextBox is called TextBox 2, you can display the text in it eg
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim text As String
    text = TextBox1.text
    TextBox2.text = text
End Sub


Note that this only works with ActiveX text boxes, not text boxes that you add using Insert | Text box.  And if you use Change event as the trigger, it'll fire every time the user types a single character. The LostFocus event might be a better choice if  you want them to enter more text.

It would be new to me that there is such a thing as a code-behind module for a Powerpoint slide. Afaik, there are only modules, forms and classes in Powerpoint

I absolutely guarantee you that there is such a thing @FunThomas ... but they are not immediately accessible in the VBE as (for example) they are for Excel Worksheets ... but if you add a Slide with an (ActiveX as pointed out by Steve Rindsberg) TextBox ... or other ActiveX Control ... select it and click on 'View Code' then it will be made accessible in the VBE.

You're right. Didn't know that - but I think I never used any ActiveX objects in PP. I try to avoid ActiveX controls in any Office application because they have so many flaws and are blocked by some companies.

@FunThomas Agreed, they're best avoided when possible. But if you need to let users enter text into a text box during a slide show, ActiveX is about the only way, short of popping an inputbox or form. Both of which are more reliable and work on Macs; ActiveX controls don't.
